# Why is svchost always taking up half of CPU?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, svchost

I notice that svchost is taking up a lot of CPU.  Here's a screen shot from Process Explorer.
[image]

The CPU utilization is always this high, even when I only have a web browser open.  I can tell because the area around my CPU is always hot.  My virus scanner, Avast, has not found anything. I ran Hitmanpro, and it didn't find any threads.  I clicked through all the processes in the above tree, and found that they are all running from C:\Windows\System32\ and are by Microsoft.

I double clicked the parent process in that tree, and here's what I see in the threads tab:
[image]

Here's what I see for the stack for wuauserv:

`ntoskrnl.exe!IoAcquireRemoveLockEx+0xe7
ntoskrnl.exe!memset+0x22a
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x2cb
ntoskrnl.exe!KeDetachProcess+0x1219
ntoskrnl.exe!PsReturnProcessNonPagedPoolQuota+0x3b3
ntoskrnl.exe!CcSetDirtyPinnedData+0x433
ntdll.dll!NtQueryPerformanceCounter+0xa
kernel32.dll!QueryPerformanceFrequency+0x17
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x152ba
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x1504f
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x78a9
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x6052
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x608c
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x5de7
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x1065f
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x122f8
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x28056
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x254e2
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x23c50
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x5755
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x4e4b
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21`

This seems to be related to Windows update.  Here's what I see when I click on the Windows Update icon the taskbar:
[image]

I'm running Vista.  I have a Thinkpad W500 with a T9600 CPU.

Comment: It would be easier for us to figure out what's going on if you go into the properties of that process, go to the "Threads" tab, and then provide the name of the service that's using all that CPU. If you could provide the stack too, that would be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CPU usage you're seeing is coming from `wuauserv`, which is the Windows Update service. What's most likely happening is that your computer is currently busy installing Windows Updates in the background.

You should be able to get more information by going into the Windows Update control panel applet. There you should also be able to customize this behavior such that Windows Update asks for your permission before installing updates.

Comment: It seems that Windows update has not checked since last month.  Does this mean that it is not actively checking?

Comment: @user2233706: you should click on "Check for updates", and see what happens. Presumably you've already tried restarting your PC? Another explanation could be that your Windows Update data is corrupted somehow and it's making the service go crazy.

Comment: From 'Change settings', I unchecked 'Give me updates for Microsoft products and check for new Optional software when I update Windows' and the CPU utilization immediately dropped to 0.  Does this mean that software like Windows Defender won't be updated?

Comment: I don't think so - it's normally quite hard to disable security updates (for obvious reasons). My knowledge of Vista is quite rusty though, so I may be wrong. Sounds like you found the source of the problem though. Maybe if you restart your PC, re-enable this option, and then check for updates again, it will finally run to completion. Or at least you'll be able to see what it's doing.